# How do I find recurring pattern lines in a large file

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a large file that contains many lines of strings in a format of:

```
A
B
D
B
C
D
C
D
C
D
```

As you can see C and D appears recurrently 3 times **next to each other** , so I want to parse the file to find the recurring pattern of them to output:

```
A
B
D
B
repeat C D 3 times
C
D
```

in actual case, it the recurring pattern of lines that next to each other may goes up to 3 lines but no more than that, e.g

```
A
B
D
B
C
D
E
C
D
E
```

So the output would be:

```
    A
    B
    D
    B
    Repeat C D E 2 times
    C
    D
    E
```

Here is the runnable code, but how could I find the longest repeat patterns if there are other repeated pattern ahead of it?

```
def is_list_equal(left, right):
    if len(left) != len(right):
        return False

    for i in xrange(len(left)):
        if left[i] != right[i]:
            return False

    return True

def find_dup_from_end(l, min_pattern_len, min_repeats):
    assert min_pattern_len * min_repeats <= len(l)
    max_pattern_len = len(l) / min_repeats
    l = l[::-1]
    for i in xrange(max_pattern_len, min_pattern_len-1, -1):
        s1 = l[:i]
        for j in range(1, min_repeats):
            s2 = l[len(s1)*j:len(s1)*(j+1)]
            if not is_list_equal(s1, s2):
                break
        else:
            return (len(l)-len(s1)*min_repeats, len(s1))

    return None, None


def find_dup(file, min_pattern_len=2, max_pattern_len=10, min_repeats=2):
    assert min_pattern_len > 0
    assert min_repeats > 1
    assert min_pattern_len <= max_pattern_len

    feed = []
    min_feed_length = min_pattern_len*min_repeats
    max_feed_length = max_pattern_len*min_repeats
    start = None
    length = None
    with open(file) as f:
        mylist = f.read().splitlines() 
        for line in mylist:
            line = line.strip()
            api = line
            fn = 'a'
            feed.append((fn, api))
            if len(feed) < min_feed_length:
                continue
            if len(feed) > max_feed_length:
                fn2, api2 = feed[0]
                print fn2, api2
                feed = feed[1:]
            feed1 = [api for _, api in feed]
            start, length = find_dup_from_end(feed1, min_pattern_len, min_repeats)
            if length:
                print(feed[start:start+length], min_repeats)
                break
#         print "length", length
        feed = feed[:(start - length*(min_repeats-1))]
        for fn2, api2 in feed:
            print fn2, api2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    find_dup('./apiLoopTest.text', 1, 2, 5)

a string1
a string2
([('a', 'string3'), ('a', 'string4')], 5)
a string3
a string4
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: I am very new to python and I thought about use map to store the string as key, number of appearance as value, however, I am not sure how to handle the case such that 2 or 3 lines as a pattern.

Comment: If you are very new, my best advice is to try things yourself. You actually learn much better that way.

Comment: @ScottHunter, thanks for suggestions and I totally agree. Any insight and comments on this implementation would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is a classical problem in CS called longest repeated substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code using the re module should give you a good starting point. Stick the example text from above and the regexp into site regex101.com for a description of the regexp and to test matches on other sample input.

```
import re

regex = r"(?P<_REP>(?P<GRP>(?:^[A-Z]$\n?){2,3})(?P=GRP)+)"

test_str = ("""\
A
B
D
B
C
D
E
C
D
E
""")

for match in re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL):
    groupdict  = match.groupdict()
    GRP, _REP = groupdict['GRP'], groupdict['_REP']
    print('The folloing group was repeated %i times from location %i\n%s'
          % ((len(_REP) + 1) / len(GRP), match.start(), GRP))
```

Output:

```
The following group was repeated 2 times from location 8
C
D
E
```